# Warning in gam with release of R 3.6.1

Tags: r

I now see a warning when running `gam()`. MWE below:

```
library(gam)
data(Boston, package = 'MASS')
model.gam <- gam(formula = medv ~ crim + zn, data = Boston)
```

The warning I receive is:

```
Warning message:
In model.matrix.default(mt, mf, contrasts) :
   non-list contrasts argument ignored
```

I think this may relate to a change in the `model.matrix()` function in the latest R release: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/NEWS.html. I did not receive a warning earlier today when running R version 3.5.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] splines   stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
[7] methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] gam_1.16      foreach_1.4.4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.1   tools_3.6.1      yaml_2.2.0      
[4] codetools_0.2-16 iterators_1.0.10
```

Comment: I do not see any warnings.

Comment: I think you're right that this warning is new.  I found what looks to be a relevant discussion on why the warning was added [here](https://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/model-matrix-default-silently-ignores-bad-contrasts-arg-td4755552.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** this looks like a (long-standing?) bug in `gam::gam` that's exposed by the new warning in version 3.6.0, but seems more or less harmless.

To see what's going on, set `options(warn=2)` (convert warnings to errors) and then run `traceback()` after the error occurs.

```
...
4: warning("non-list contrasts argument ignored")
3: model.matrix.default(mt, mf, contrasts)
2: model.matrix(mt, mf, contrasts)
1: gam(formula = medv ~ crim + zn, data = Boston)
```

OK, the fact that the warning/error occurs inside `model.matrix.default()` is not surprising. We have to examine/debug `gam::gam` to see what's going on.  If we examine the source code, the *only* place that "contrasts" occurs is:

```
X <- if (!is.empty.model(mt)) 
    model.matrix(mt, mf, contrasts)
```

`contrasts` is not an argument to the function, and can't have come from the `...` argument. The `...` argument gets passed through to `gam.control()`, which also has a `...` argument -- which it silently ignores!  Thus if you used `gam(..., contrasts=contr.sum)` (or something like that) in the past, thinking it would change the contrasts, you were wrong.  The only reason that this use of `contrasts` did not throw a warning (for the use of an undefined global variable) is that there is a `stats::contrasts` function that would be found.

It would be public-spirited to e-mail the maintainer (`maintainer("gam")`) and let them know about this. Two possible fixes would be (1) remove the `contrasts` argument from the `model.matrix` call or (2) add a `contrasts` argument to `gam()` (default value `NULL`) that will be passed through.