# `non-list contrasts argument ignored` in gam()

Tags: r, gam

I got the following warning of `non-list contrasts argument ignored`. Does anybody know what is wrong? Thanks.

```
R> tmp=data.frame(x=seq_len(100), y=rpois(seq_len(100), lambda=seq_len(100)/10))
R> library(gam)
Loading required package: splines
Loading required package: foreach
Loaded gam 1.16.1

Warning message:
package ‘foreach’ was built under R version 3.6.2 
R> fit=gam(y~s(x), family=poisson, data=tmp)
Warning message:
In model.matrix.default(mt, mf, contrasts) :
  non-list contrasts argument ignored
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57664927/warning-in-gam-with-release-of-r-3-6-1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Warning in gam with release of R 3.6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57664927/warning-in-gam-with-release-of-r-3-6-1)